# Allowing apache access to a subdirectory in a home directory without access to the home directory

Tags: permissions, apache2, home-directory

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 desktop with encrypted home directories. I do development work on my computer and I want to have my webroot directory to be within my home directory so it is encrypted with the rest of my home directory. As I am the only use of the machine, I want to configure Apache to point to this directly.

Current I have changed the `/var/www` folder into a symbolic link to the workspace in my hone dir: `/home/valorin/workspace`

However, this throws **403 Forbidden** errors in apache.

I have added my user into the `www-data` group, and set the ownership & permissions on the workspace folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 valorin www-data  4096 2011-04-23 10:02 workspace
```

But the only way I can get it to work is to change my home dir group to be www-data and set permissions too. I don't really want to do this as it means Apache has access to my home dir and could possibly be used by someone on my network to get into my personal data.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can leave your $HOME dir ownership alone. You don't need to set it to www-data. What you *do* have to do is ensure that Apache has execute permissions on $HOME and everything above it. So, you could do something like this:

```
chmod 751 "$HOME"
sudo chmod 751 /home
```

However, the fact that $HOME is encrypted might pose major problems for Apache unless you can somehow configure Apache to use the proper decryption key.

EDIT:

Setting execute permissions on a directory means only that you can access something inside the directory if you already know its name and if what you're trying to access also has correct permissions. So setting a global x-bit on $HOME isn't too much of a security risk, as long as all your other files have reasonable permissions. You might want to look into your umask to be sure.

Comment: Awesome, that worked, thanks :)
In regards to the encryption, when I am logged in the folder is accessible to the system - so this is not an issue (luckily!). Does that mean that any user can execute/run scripts within my home dir if they know the path? or do they need Read access for that too?

Comment: They also need read permission.

Comment: I was hoping that was the answer, thanks heaps once again :)

Comment: @Valorin: If you intend for Apache to only be able to serve pages while you're logged in, then I'm assuming it's just being used as a development box. In that case, you might also consider configuring Apache to only serve pages to 127.0.0.1. That will provide a bit on additional security.

Comment: Yep, it's a development machine and I've already configured localhost access only :)

Comment: Is there also way to just give those rights to Apache instead of to everyone? (Or, in what is Apache different from other users that it can execute without read access?)

Comment: @Lode: Which rights do you mean? Apache isn't a special case, and setting the x-bit on your $HOME is no security risk if the permissions on the files inside $HOME are reasonable. I suggest you read up on Linux/UNIX permissions. There are ways to get more granularity in permissions, but they aren't enabled by default in Ubuntu. I believe that SELinux is one such solution.