# Give access to php to /home folder

Tags: 14.04, permissions, apache2, lamp, virtualhost

I am need for apache to have access on all (well... most anyway) user folders on the same machine, so that I can access some data, do some magic and then display them on a webpage for remote viewing.

What I thought would be the simplest solution is to create a dir alias that points to /home folder and allowing it to be accessed only locally, since all the "magic" will be happening server side and only the results will be shown. Problem is I cannot make the Alias to work.

I added the following in my `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf` to check if it is working:

```
Alias /home/ "/home"
<Directory "/home">
     Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

but I'm getting a `403 Forbidden`.
I also tried adding it as a virtual host on `sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and `apache2.conf` neither of which worked.

I also added www-data to a user group that has access to /home, just to be sure.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try the solution here.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/36533/allowing-apache-access-to-a-subdirectory-in-a-home-directory-without-access-to-t?rq=1

Comment: I gave 751 to /home, nothing changed, I even tried changing it to my user home dir and changing everything in there to give ex to all users and make `/home` point to it, still nothing. I also added a sub folder in my root site with the same name, but it does not access that, anything else I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fiddling with all those files, I simply did the following two steps:

1. added the folders I needed to a group in which www-data is a member of and granted the group both read and execute permissions (for some reason execute was not enough), thanks [Brian](https://askubuntu.com/users/508889/brian)
2. Added what I originally had in my `alias.conf` to `apache2.conf`

Obviously I first removed all the havoc I had created in my previous attempts.